# Relationship between dft and dtft.

Tags: signal-processing

Let X(e jω) is the DTFT of a discrete-time signal x[n] given as x[n] =(1/3)^n u[n].Determine a 6-point causal sequence a[n] whose 6-point DFT A[k] is the 6 samples of the DTFT X(ejω) such that  A[k] = X(ej2πk/6 ) for k = 0, 1. . , 5 can I find the answer by without actually calculating dft or dtft.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.